# How to iteratively call a function with ref argument and update state?

Tags: rust

This is a minimal example. I have a function `foo` that takes a reference of a vector and returns a brand new vector. Then, there's another function `bar` that iteratively calls `foo` and update its state. But I cannot get it to compile.

```
fn foo(input: &Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let len = input.len();
    return input[0..len-1].to_vec();
}

fn bar() {
    let input = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    let mut out = &input;
    for _ in 0..2 {
        out = foo(out);
    }
}
```

Gives this error:

```
78 |         out = foo(out);
   |               ^^^^^^^^
   |               |
   |               expected `&Vec<i32>`, found struct `Vec`
   |               help: consider borrowing here: `&foo(out)`
```

So that makes sense since `out` has a mismatched type of `&Vec<i32>`. Now, if I add an ampersand in front of the `foo(out)` call, then I got a different error:

```
78 |         out = &foo(out);
   |                ^^^^---^- temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                |   |
   |                |   borrow later used here
   |                creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
```

What is the right way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean way, if possible, is to consistently hold onto the actual value instead of a reference:

```
fn bar() {
    let input = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    let mut out = input;
    for _ in 0..2 {
        out = foo(&out);
    }
}
```

or, equivalently,

```
fn bar() {
    let input = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    let out = (0..2).fold(input, |prev, _| foo(&prev));
}
```

But if you need to continue using `input` afterwards, then you’ll have to find some other way to make the return value of `foo` live longer than the loop, e.g.

```
fn bar() {
    let input = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    let mut out_storage;
    let mut out = &input;
    for _ in 0..2 {
        out_storage = foo(out);
        out = &out_storage;
    }
}
```